# Change wordpress site language without changing the admin dashboard language

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.0

I'm using Wordpress 4.1, when I go to Settings -> General and then I choose a language in the combobox Site Language, that successfully changes the language of my WordPress site (although not completely, I don't know why). The problem is, that also changes the language of my admin Dashboard to the language that I chose there. I want my admin Dashboard to stay in English. How do I change my WordPress site language without changing my admin dashboard language?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Also see [Localization: I want the backend: english and frontend in defined language](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/localization-i-want-the-backend-english-and-frontend-in-defined-language) and [Different Language for Frontend and Backend](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/different-language-for-frontend-and-backend).  Finally there is a plugin that's supposed to accomplish this (I haven't used it yet) [English WordPress Admin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/english-wp-admin/)

Answer (score 9):

You can change the global site language under Settings > General, but then edit your user account to set the admin language to whatever you want for your user account.  For more info reference https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-7-to-introduce-user-specific-language-setting-for-the-admin

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you're using a separate plugin. You may want to look into the [WPML (Wordpress Multilanguage) plugin](http://wpml.org/). This will allow you to translate the pages/posts but the admin interface doesn't change.

Comment: Separete plugin? I was not even aware of a WordPress language plugin. Sorry I'm a beginner to WordPress

Comment: This plugin is not even free. I'm sure there is a FREE solution to do what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I've used this plugin several times: https://wordpress.org/plugins/xili-language/
It's pretty complete and easy to use.

And the main plugin is free, which allows you to do almost everything.